# How to get Thread Dump and Heap Dump in case of RabbitMQ Server?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, heap-dump, thread-dump

Is it possible to get Thread Dump and Heap Dump in case of a RabbitMQ Server?

To be Specific:
The RabbitMQ server I am referring to runs on a docker and I want to get Thread Dump and Heap Dump in such a case which would be useful in disaster analysis or other preventive alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my colleague said in [the mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/EcoczSdcBD4/discussion), core files are of little use to just about anyone using RabbitMQ. In the case of a server crash having robust monitoring in place with historical data combined with RabbitMQ's logs will be of more use. Don't forget that proper logging of client-side exceptions and errors is necessary as well.